# Magento 2: Importing Customer information shows validation error 1. Please enter a password with a valid length. in row(s)1

Tags: magento2, customer, import

I am importing customer information in magento 2 with password 4 characters, I have also changed the password length to 4 in Stores->Configuration->Customer Configuration.

But still shows the same error **(1. Please enter a password with a valid length. in row(s): 1)**

But while creating a new account it is accepting the password length with 4 characters but while importing I am not able to do this.

Please someone help me on this.

Comment: try to clear the cache after change the configuration